# Make "org-edit-special" not insert spaces at the beginning of the line

Tags: org-mode

## The problem

When editing code blocks, I usually opens a new buffer by pressing `C-c '` (i.e. executing `org-edit-special`). The problem is that when I finish editing the buffer, two spaces are inserted to the beginning of each line which is something I don't want so I would like to make `org-edit-special` not insert those spaces after finishing editing the buffer that it opens.

In the gif shown below, you can see how two spaces are inserted at the beginning of each line after exiting the buffer that `org-edit-special` opens.

[image]

## Some notes

- I started emacs with `emacs -Q` to avoid my configuration interfere with the default functionality of`org-mode`.
- The gif starts when the black box appears  at the right top corner and finishes when the `C-c /` key is pressed (it is shown by `screenkey`).

Comment: Are you looking for `org-edit-src-content-indentation`?

Comment: Yep. Writing `(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 0)` in my config solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing `C-c '` executes `org-edit-special`. This functions calls `org-edit-src-code` when the cursor is inside a source code block.

The following quote was retrieved from the documentation of the variable `org-edit-src-content-indentation`.

> This should be the number of spaces added to the indentation of the #+begin line in order to compute the indentation of the block content after editing it with ‘M-x org-edit-src-code’.

So if you want no spaces to be added to each line, you need to set that value to 0.

```
(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 0)
```